# Creating new Column if an other column equal a specific value in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this

```
id     |     type          |   value

   1   |     type1         |   v1
   1   |     type2         |   v2
   1   |     type3         |   v3
   1   |     type4         |   v4
```

I want to use this conditions.

```
IF type= type1 THEN create new column that name is 'val1'
IF type= type2 THEN create new column that name is 'val2'
IF type= type3 THEN create new column that name is 'val3'
```

And No column created for type4

I want this table after run query:

```
id     |     val1          |   val2     | val3

 1     |     v1            |   v2       |  v3
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server <> Oracle. If you're going to tag an RDBMS, then tag ***only*** the RDBMS you are actually using. Don't just tag lots of them to try and get your question more views. Every RDBMS uses a different dialect of SQL, making it impossible to answer if we don't know what RDBMS you are *really* using.

Comment: Do you want to create a new column in the sense of `alter table add val1 varchar2(2)`, or do you want a query to display an additional column with values depending on some logic?

Comment: Please edit this Question to remove "Create column". It seems from the accepted Answer that you wanted to retrieve values, not modify your table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using conditional aggregation

```
select id,
max(case when type='type1' then value end) as val1,
max(case when type='type2' then value end) as val2,
max(case when type='type3' then value end) as val3
from tablename
group by id
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works for me. I want to select another column that concatenate all other types. For example if we have type4, type5 and type 6. The new column should contain "val4 | val5 | val6". How can I add this to the brevious script. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One option would be using [`PIVOT`](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/database/sql-11g-pivot.html) clause provided your DB version is 11g+ :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM t -- > your table
 PIVOT (MAX( value ) FOR type IN ( 'type1' AS val1, 'type2' AS val2, 'type3' AS val3 ))
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ba23e9a4398aa84dc6a16798b48b9996)</kbd>

Comment: this is a great answer :)

Comment: yours too as ever @Fahmi :)